# A Separate Usercontrol executing a method in another Usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I am making a little game in WPF to understand it better, I have a parent control that has 2 child usercontrols.

The first child user control has buttons that update the position of an object in the second usercontrol.

In the MainWindow.xaml.cs
I have

```
controllersplaceholder.Content = new ControllerView1()
gameplaceholder.Content = new GameView1()
```

As you can see, controllersplaceholder has no knowledge whatsoever of GameView1. 
To update a position of an element in GameView1 I would have to pass GameView1 reference into ControllerView1 and execute methods in GameView1(). 
Question is how can I do it so that 
ControllerView1,ControllerView2 will execute methods in GameView1 easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**events**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx). Simply declare an event on your `ControllerView1`, say:

```
public event EventHandler RequestReposition;
```

When creating your objects, make `GameView1` subscribe and react to controller's event:

```
var controller = new ControllerView1();
var gameView = new GameView1();
// here we're subscribing to controller's event
controller.RequestReposition += gameView.UpdatePosition;
controllersplaceholder.Content = controller;
gameplaceholder.Content = gameView;
```

Now, whenever you *raise an event* from controller, whoever subscribed will be notified and proper actions will be taken (execution of subscribed methods).

Note that your game view method doesn't have to match event signature exactly; with a little help from anonymous methods you can create matching event handler on the fly and use already existing methods from `GameView1`:

```
// subscribtion with lambda
controller.RequestReposition += (sender, args) =>
    {
        gameView.UpdatePosition();
        gameView.Refresh();
    };
```

Comment: Hi, would this be able to pass information from ControllerView to GameView as well? I was thinking of using a DTO.. but if I can avoid that the better

Comment: @LewsTherin: naturally. Events in .NET allow you to pass any arguments via [`EventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.aspx) class and classes deriving from it (you can create your custom ones).

Comment: @LewsTherin Yes, you can.  Make properties in `controller` for the information you want to send, and properties in `gameView` for what it needs to receive.  The contents of the lambda the answer above uses could set the value of `gameview` with the relevant property from `controller`.

Comment: @jimmy_keen This solution sounds like the one I need. 
I assume I have to write documentation to let others know that the controller should fire events for it to talk to the GameView.

Comment: @LewsTherin: in MVC/MVP patterns (assuming you're using one of it or derivatives) most communication is done via [observer/publisher-subscriber pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). In .NET, this pattern is implemented with *events* and indeed it's utilized in various non-tightly coupled communication scenarios.

Comment: @jimmy_keen I am actually using MVVM which is very difficult to get right :(
I will give it a shot thanks.